# Is the output of a smoothed rectifier same as the DC output of a battery?

Tags: rectifier

When rectifying an AC signal to DC through full wave rectification and smoothing using capacitors, is the output same as that of a DC battery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, because the smoothing reduces the output impedance of the adapter, and increasing the output impedance means increasing the ripple. Even adding a linear regulator won't eliminate all the ripple.